# switch case to find maximum or equal in c isnt working

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am using switch case to find the maximum of two numbers and to print another statement if they are equal. However, my code doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
    switch(num1 > num2)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Number1 is greater than Number2");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Number2 is greater than Number1");
            break;

    }
    switch(num1 == num2)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Number1 is equal to Number2");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Number1 is not equal to Number2");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  You're using a dubious return type for `main()`; you're not terminating your messages with a newline.  You have your logic inverted (0 is false; 1 is true).

Comment: so do i write int main() instead of void main(). i corrected the logic of 0 and 1.

Comment: @izz123 it has to be either num1 is greater than num2, or vice versa. or if they are equal it should display that they are both equal

Comment: Ideally `int main(void)` when you're not using the arguments, though `int main()` also works OK.  If your compiler doesn't support C99 or later, you should then add `return 0;` (actually, I add that even though there are those who'd argue it isn't necessary).

Comment: You should use `case 0:` for false and `default:` for true, since any non-0 value is true, and in other circumstances  - say the return value from `isdigit()` -  `case 1:` would be incorrect.

Comment: Strictly, the message in the 'false' case for `num1 > num2` should be `num2 is greater than or equal to num1`.  It's also a good idea to print the actual values you compare — it's a basic form of checking that the computer sees the values you expect it to see.

Comment: bizz123 do not add [answered] after accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the numbers are equal, `num1 > num2` will be false, so you'll go into the first case of the first switch, which incorrectly claims that `num2 > num1`. There are three possibilities, but this condition can only return 2 different results.

You need to nest them rather than do them sequentially.

```
switch (num1 == num2) {
case 1:
    printf("Number1 is equal to Number2");
    break;
case 0:
    switch (num1 > num2) {
    case 1:
        printf("Number1 is greater than Number2");
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("Number2 is greater than Number1");
        break;
    }
    printf("Number1 is not equal to Number1");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach

```
switch( ( num2 < num1 ) - ( num1 < num2 ) )
{
    case -1:
        puts( "Number2 is greater than Number1" );
        break;
    case 0:
        puts( "Number1 is equal to Number2" );
        break;
    case 1:
        puts( "Number1 is greater than Number2" );
        break;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

    printf( "Enter two numbers: " );
    scanf( "%d%d", &num1, &num2 );

    switch( ( num2 < num1 ) - ( num1 < num2 ) )
    {
    case -1:
        puts( "Number2 is greater than Number1" );
        break;
    case 0:
        puts( "Number1 is equal to Number2" );
        break;
    case 1:
        puts( "Number1 is greater than Number2" );
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
Enter two numbers: 10 20
Number2 is greater than Number1
```

It is the best approach among the all others shown here.:) It uses only one switch statement.

Comment: what does -1 stand for?

Comment: @bizz123 For the case when num1 is less than num2.

Comment: MInor thought: for _maximum_, using `>` is easier to follow than `<`.  Other than that code is good and diomatic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to check is your scanf did not fail.

```
int main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    if(scanf("%d,%d",&num1,&num2) == 2)
    {
        switch(num1 > num2)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Number1 is greater than Number2");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Number2 is greater than Number1");
                break;

        }
        switch(num1 == num2)
        {
            case 0:
                printf("Number1 is equal to Number2");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("Number1 is not equal to Number2");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Scanf failed!!!\n");
    }
}
```

Usually it is better to avoid user input when testing some ideas.

```
int main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    for(int index =0; index < 50; index++)
    {
        num1 = rand() % 50;
        num2 = rand() % 50;

        printf("Numbers : %d, %d - ", num1, num2);
        switch(num1 > num2)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Number1 is greater than Number2\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Number2 is greater than Number1\n");
                break;

        }
        switch(num1 == num2)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Number1 is equal to Number2\n");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("Number1 is not equal to Number2\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then is easy to spot that 1 & 0 has to be swapped as zero means false and 1 true;

```
    switch(num1 > num2)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Number1 is greater than Number2");
```

So if `num1 > num2` is the truth then the result of this logical expression will be 1 not zero

But you have also many other logical errors (not  really programming - just the simple logic). If num1 > num2 id not `true` it does mean that the num2 is greater than num1. It can be also equal;

So you should change the text in the switch to:

```
        case 0:
            printf("Number2 is greater than Number1 or they are equal\n");
            break;
```

Comment: When values are equal, final code will print "Number2 is greater than Number1" –

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica of couse it is. I just wanted to show the main errors

Answer (score 0):

You have made one mistake in logic at the second switch case is num1 and num2 both are having equal value then they then te output of `num1 == num2` will be `1` and if both are having different values it will return 0. So, you also need to change the `print1` statement for the second switch case.

Your, full functioning code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1,num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers:");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
    switch(num1 > num2)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Number1 is greater than Number2");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Number2 is greater than Number1");
            break;
    }

    switch(num1 == num2)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("Number1 is not equal to Number2");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("Number1 is equal to Number2");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When values are equal, code will print  "Number1 is greater than Number2"

Comment: When `num1 > num2`, code prints errant "Number2 is greater than Number1"